# Microsoft App Installer protests isufficient minimum OS version of Windows App SDK bundle

Tags: uwp, msbuild, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I have a Microsoft Store app built with WinUI 3 and the Windows App SDK 1.0.0, built on a Windows 11 machine.
When attempting to install the bundle on a Windows 10 machine, the Installer fails on insufficient compatibility since

- the package requires OS version 10.0.22000.0,
- the device runs on version 10.0.19044.1766.

however, I set both the desktop project and package to target 10.0.22000.0 but support OS version back to 10.0.17763.0.

[image]

[image]

Both reference the Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools 10.0.22000.196.

Comment: There is no problem with the version,How did you package the program? you can try [Windows-app-sdk-1.1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/release-channels)

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I'm bundling through Project->Publish->Create App Packages and then set for sideloading with a custom certificate. Targeting the SDK with 1.1.1 is currently not an option as it "requires WinRT.Runtime.dll version 1.6 or greater", which if I'm not mistaken requires .NET 6 (migrating is currently not possible).